# dblquad in scipy vs. matlab giving different results

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, scipy, numerical-integration

I want to double integrate a function. But I get different results when using `dblquad` over `scipy.integrate` and `matlab`. A python implementation of my function to double integrate is like this:

```
###Python implementation##
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import dblquad

def InitialCondition(x_b, y_b, m10, m20, N0):

    IC = np.zeros((len(x_b)-1,len(y_b)-1))
    for i in xrange(len(x_b) - 1):
        for j in xrange(len(y_b) - 1):
            IC[i,j], abserr =  dblquad(ExponenIC, x_b[i], x_b[i + 1], lambda x: y_b[j], lambda x: y_b[j+1], args=(m10, m20, N0), epsabs=1.49e-15, epsrel=1.49e-15)
    return IC

def ExponenIC(x, y, m10, m20, N0):

    retVal = (16 * N0) / (m10 * m20) * (x / m10)* (y / m20) * np.exp(-2 * (x / m10) - 2 * (y / m20))

    return retVal


if __name__=='__main__':
    x_min, x_max  = 0.0004, 20.0676
    x_b = np.exp(np.linspace(np.log(x_min), np.log(x_max), 4))
    y_b = np.copy(x_b)
    m10, m20, N0 = 0.04, 0.04, 1
    print InitialCondition(x_b, y_b, m10, m20, N0)
```

But if I repeat the same in matlab, with equivalent implementation and same input as shown below:

```
%%%Matlab equivalent%%%
function IC = test(x_b, y_b, m10, m20, N0)
for i = 1:length(x_b)-1
      for j = 1:length(y_b)-1
          IC(i, j) = dblquad(@ExponenIC, x_b(i), x_b(i+1), y_b(j), y_b(j+1), 1e-6, @quad, m10, m20, N0);
      end
end
return

function retVal = ExponenIC(x, y, m10, m20, N0)

 retVal = (16 * N0) / (m10*m20) * (x / m10) .* (y / m20) .* exp(-2*(x/m10) - 2 * (y/m20));  

return

% for calling
x_min = 0.0004;
x_max = 20.0676;
x_b  =  exp(linspace(log(x_min), log(x_max), 4));
y_b = x_b;
m10 =  0.04;
m20  =  0.04;
N0 = 1;
I = test(x_b, y_b, m10, m20, N0)
```

Scipy `dblquad` returns:

```
[[  2.84900512e-02   1.40266599e-01   7.34019842e-12]
 [  1.40266599e-01   6.90582083e-01   3.61383932e-11]
 [  7.28723691e-12   3.58776449e-11   1.89113430e-21]]
```

and Matlab `dblquad` returns:

```
IC =
    28.4901e-003   140.2666e-003   144.9328e-012
   140.2666e-003   690.5820e-003   690.9716e-012
   144.9328e-012   690.9716e-012   737.2926e-021
```

I have tried to change tolerances and order of input but two solutions remained always different. Thus, I am not able to understand which one is accurate and I would like to have it correct in python. Can someone suggest if this is a bug in either of the `dblquad`solver or in my code somewhere?

Comment: Are those solutions really different? What is the floating point eps on the system you are using?

Comment: @talonmies yes, they are different. The Matlab solution are 20-200 times larger than python. During post processing of this result, the difference becomes very evident. The floating point eps for python is `np.finfo(x_b[0]).eps= 2.2204460492503131e-16`.

Comment: Could you edit the python code to create a complete, self-contained example that we can copy and run?  I haven't been able to reproduce the the values that you show for the scipy output.

Comment: Also, your integral can be done analytically, so you could eliminate the use of `dblquad`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I have made the python code as self-contained example. Analytical solution can be another option, but this kind of challenge exists for other cases as well.

Comment: You can use the exact solution to help answer your question.  For the region x_b[2] < x < x_b[3], y_b[2] < y < y_b[3], I get the exact value to be 1.8639...e-21.  The closest I get to that using scipy's `dblquad` is 1.877...e-21, and that required using `epsabs=1e-21` (which is dicey--the answer is of the same magnitude as the requested error tolerance).  Your matlab code, on the other hand, is only using a tolerance of 1e-6!  Try running your matlab code with a much smaller tolerance.

Comment: In matlab with epsabs/tol=1e-15 IC[3,1]=7.2872e-012, but IC[3,3]= 737.2926e-021 as before. The above piece of matlab code is also now like self-contained example.

Comment: I don't know if it will make a difference, but have you tried matlab's `integral2` function (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html)?

Comment: Not yet, but I am more interested in python solution. The difference between Python and Matlab results were giving doubt as final results after complete model simulation in Matlab is more closer to the analytical solution of the model when compared to python results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a glance at the results, the repetition of 690 in the Matlab output (in places where Python has different results) casts a doubt on Matlab's performance.

One of problems with using the (deprecated) function `dblquad` in Matlab is that the tolerance you specify to it is *absolute* (to my understanding). This is why when you specify 1e-6, the integrals of order 1e-11 come out wrong. When you replace it by 1e-12, the computation takes a lot longer (because the larger integrals must now be computed to a great precision), yet the smallest of integrals, of size 1e-21, is still wrong.

Hence, you should use a routine that supports relative error tolerance, such as `integral2`.

Replacing the Matlab line with `dblquad` by

```
IC(i, j) = integral2(@(x,y) ExponenIC(x,y, m10, m20, N0), x_b(i), x_b(i+1), y_b(j), y_b(j+1), 'RelTol', 1e-12);
```

I get

```
0.0284900512006556     0.14026659933722     7.10653215130477e-12
0.14026659933722       0.690582082532588    3.51109000906259e-11 
7.10653215130476e-12   3.5110900090626e-11  1.78512164747727e-21
```

which roughly agrees with Python output. Still, there remains a substantial difference. To settle the matter definitely, I calculated the integrals analytically. The exact result is

```
 0.0284900512006717     0.140266599337199     7.28723691243472e-12 
 0.140266599337199      0.690582082532677     3.58776449039036e-11 
 7.28723691243472e-12   3.58776449039036e-11  1.86394265998016e-21
```

Neither package achieved the desired accuracy, but Python/scipy was much closer.

---

For completeness, the loop that outputs the analytic solution:

```
function IC = test(x_b, y_b, m10, m20, N0)
F = @(x,a)  -0.25*exp(-2*x/a)*(2*x+a);
for i = 1:length(x_b)-1
      for j = 1:length(y_b)-1
          IC(i,j) = (16 * N0) / (m10*m20) *(F(x_b(i+1),m10)-F(x_b(i),m10)) * (F(y_b(j+1),m20)-F(y_b(j),m20));
      end
end
end
```